# How do I bulk update records using simple-salesforce?

Tags: update, bulk-api, simple-salesforce, updaterecord

I am successfully performing a bulk query operation using simple salesforce to obtain the Id's I want to work with, but when I perform a bulk update like this:

```
data=[{'Id': '1', 'Date__c': '12/01/2022'},
 {'Id': '2', 'Date__c': '12/02/2022'},
 {'Id': '3', 'Date__c': '12/01/2022'},
 {'Id': '4', 'Date__c': '12/02/2022'},
 {'Id': '5', 'Date__c': '12/01/2022'}]

sf.bulk.Account.update(data, batch_size=200, use_serial=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://[redacted link information]. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

when I click on the error link I get the following:
InvalidUrl
Failed to parse URL. Was expecting 'request' or 'result' but found:result.

I've tried to find documentation on the bulk library but it is very sparse. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Likely an issue with the format of the date field: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/366

Comment: I get you're trying to protect some potentially confidential information, but you're not being specific enough. For example, we don't know what endpoint you're hitting, so we don't even know if this is a Bulk 1.0 or Bulk 2.0 request, or what's going on. We need enough information to at least figure out what direction to look in.

Comment: @identigral, that thread was closed without actually solving or determining if the date formatting was an issue. I'm formatting the date as a string so any specific recommendation on the format would be very helpful.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I'm hitting the Account standard object in salesforce. I'm not entirely sure what information you'd need since all i've hidden is the link to our personalized salesforce. To clarify a point earlier, I successfully completed a bulk account query operation so I suppose I'm using v1? Any pointers on how to see which version of bulk api we're using?

Comment: @TylerDavis https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/366#issuecomment-598218217

Comment: @TylerDavis The host/domain is personalized, sure, but the actual URL would have clues like `/services/data/v55.0/bulk/...` that would demonstrate what API you're using.

Comment: @sfdcfox https://URL/services/async/42.0/job/JOBID/batch/BATCHID/result

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for pointing me to the specific comment. That formatting seems to have done something here. I'm going to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only does the date field need to be a string, it also needs to be formatted in yyyy-mm-dd format, regardless of if you've selected the display settings as mm-dd-yyyy.

convert the date to a string using strftime:

```
data['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```